# Using WebKitCSSMatrix's rotateAxisAngle method, how can I effectively set the previous rotation as the default rotation for that element?

Tags: javascript, css

I've not played around with WebKitCSSMatrix properties before, so I decided to give myself a challenge by making a web-based Rubik's cube. This is something which has been done before, but I figured I'd try it from scratch (without looking at any other sources). However I've now hit a bit of a wall when it comes to rotating each individual cube.

Here is what I currently have: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/S5VqB/)**. (Yes, this is only a 2x2 cube for now).

Note that the axes themselves do not rotate as a whole yet, I'm only concentrating on the individual cube rotation for now.

In order to rotate each side, you simply need to click and drag. So for instance if you click the top-left red square and drag your cursor right you'll spin each of the top row of cubes anticlockwise to the right.

As you can see each of the cubes for each axis rotate correctly if only done one way (or the opposite way), but when you combine two axes the rotation messes up. This is happening because I assume my use of the `rotateAxisAngle()` method isn't stacking with the previous rotation.

For example, if we grab the top left red square on the front face and drag right we end up with this:

[image: red top left front rotated right]

Here the `case ('right')` rotation has been triggered and `rotateAxisAngle(0, 1, 0, 90)` has been applied. The red cube has rotated anticlockwise to the right and now the white face is on the front as desired. This red cube now has the following `style`:

```html
<div
    class="cube"
    style="
        -webkit-transform: matrix3d( 0,  0, -1,  0,
                                     0,  1,  0,  0,
                                     1,  0,  0,  0,
                                     0,  0,  0,  1 );
"> ... </div>
```

If we now grab the same square and move it downwards, the blue face on top should end up in front. This is where the problem lies. In doing this, we end up with this:

[image: same red square after rotating right rotated down]

Instead of rotating the cube clockwise downwards, the cube has instead rotated anticlockwise to the right. The matrix has been transformed to:

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d( 0,  0, -1,  0,
                            -1,  0,  0,  0,
                             0,  1,  0,  0,
                             0,  0,  0,  1 );
```

The desired matrix should instead be:

```
-webkit-transform: matrix3d( 0, -1,  0,  0,
                             0,  0, -1,  0,
                             1,  0,  0,  0,
                             0,  0,  0,  1 );
```

What do I need to do in order to stack the new rotation on top of the previous rotation as if the previous rotation was the cube's default rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when doing a matrices transform, (in your case the rotation), you multiply the original matrix by the transform.

And, when you do that, you can choose between right multiplication and left multiplication.

Unfortunately, rotateAxisAngle is doing the oposite multiplication of what you want.

As far as I know, there isn't anyway to tell rotateAxisAngle to change the behaviour, so you will need to do it by hand.

I have choose to have an identity matrix in a separate variable, and then to do the rotation, rotate the identity matrix and multiply the result to the current transform of the element.

That is:

```
var identity = new WebKitCSSMatrix();
identity.m11 = 1;
identity.m22 = 1;
identity.m33 = 1;
identity.m44 = 1;

    
$(function() {
    var
        $body = $('body'),
        $wrapper = $('#rubiks > .wrapper'),
        $rubiks = $('#rubiks'),
        spinable = true
    ;
    $.fn.extend({
        spin: function(x,y,z,direction) {
            if(this.selector === '#rubiks') {
                switch(direction) {
                    case ('left'):
                        $('div.axis[data-y="'+y+'"]').each(function() { 
                            var $this = $(this);
                            $cube = $this.find('.cube');
                            transformMatrix = $this.css('transform').split(', ');
                            matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix($cube[0].style.webkitTransform);
                            transform = identity.rotateAxisAngle(0, 1, 0, -90);
                            matrix = transform.multiply(matrix);
                            $cube[0].style.webkitTransform = matrix.toString();
                        });
                        break;
                    case ('right'):
                        $('div.axis[data-y="'+y+'"]').each(function() {
                            var $this = $(this);
                            $cube = $this.find('.cube');
                            transformMatrix = $this.css('transform').split(', ');
                            matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix($cube[0].style.webkitTransform);
                            transform = identity.rotateAxisAngle(0, 1, 0, 90);
                            matrix = transform.multiply(matrix);
                            $cube[0].style.webkitTransform = matrix.toString();
                        });
                        break;
```

I have post only 2 cases, the remaining are the same.

### [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5VqB/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there anything I can do to correct the rotation when it reaches 360 degrees? For instance, if you grab the front-facing top left cube and rotate it left and then down twice the rotation loops around, causing an undesired effect.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. May be I don't understand it exactly, or maybe it is navigator related. I am using Chrome  29.0.1547.76 m on Win 7.

Comment: I'm using the same version of Chrome and same OS. To reproduce: 1. Click on the top left red square. 2. drag left. 3. Click on the black square which is now where the red square just was. 4. Drag down. 5. Click on the blue square which is now in its place. 6. Drag down again, this time watch the animation of that cube and the top-facing white cube behind it.

Comment: I have found out why I don't see the problem. In flags, I have set "disable-threaded-animation". That solves the problem. However, if I go back to standard configuration, the problem appears again. Looks like it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was deleted, so I couldn't improve it..

I have found that using Chrome's (and perhaps other browsers') getComputedStyle method is useful in allowing you to make local or global rotations on a set of objects. (See below:not full code, but the gist of it (full code in the fiddle).

With respect to the exact question - there are 2 ways to add a transformation to the current transformation value, and I have outlined them below:

Imagine your object is the Rubik's cube. A global rotation around the y-axis would mean that the cube rotate around an axis that is parallel to your body length vector (or just your own UP). A local rotation around the y-axis would be a rotation of the cube around whatever vector is coming out of the side labeled "original Y". In other words, if you define the cube with the RED center side facing up, then you can move the cube around any which way, and a local y-axis rotation would not change the direction the red center square is facing.

```
<div id="someForm">
  ...any number of 3d transformed objects...
</div>
```

```
.someForm{
      transform: someTransform();
      webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;

      webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```
var someForm = document.getElementById('someForm');
function rotateAroundAxis(axis,angle,coordSys){  
   //axis in ['X','Y','Z'];
   //angle is numeric;
   //coordSys in ['local','global']
   var oldTransform = window.getComputedStyle(someForm).transform;
       oldTransform = oldTransform!='none' ? oldTransform : ''; 
   var newTransform = ' rotate' + axis + '('+angle+'deg) ';
   var totalTransform;
   if(coordSys==='global'){
        totalTransform = oldTransform + newTransform;
   }else{ // coordSys==='local'
        totalTransform = newTransform + oldTransform+;
   }
   someForm.style.transform = totalTransform;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/weya02t3/